# How can I return a row for each group even if there were no results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a database containing customer orders. These orders contain the customer id, order month, order year, order half month( either first half 'FH' or last half 'LH' of the month), and quantity ordered.

I want to query monthly totals for each customer for given month.  Here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT id, half_month, month, year, SUM(nbr_ord)
FROM Orders
WHERE month = 7
      AND year = 2015
GROUP BY id, half_month, year, month
```

The problem with this is that if a customer did not order anything during one half_month there will not be a row returned for that period.

I want there to be a row for each customer for every half month. If they didn't order anything during a half month then a row should be returned with their id, the month, year, half month, and 0 for number ordered.

Comment: Databases can't report on data that doesn't exist.  Where should the database go to get years and months where order's where not place?  You can create this missing data and use an OUTER join to ensure all dates/periods are included: as shown in previous stack examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592930/oracle-select-missing-dates or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989561/find-missing-dates-using-sql

Comment: @xQbert . . . You misunderstand the request.  The date parts exist, just not assigned to a particular customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, generate all the rows, which you can do with a `cross join` of the customers and the time periods.  Then, bring in the information for the aggregation:

```
select i.id, t.half_month, t.month, t.year, coalesce(sum(nbr_ord), 0)
from (select distinct id from orders) i cross join
     (select distinct half_month, month, year
      from orders
      where month = 7 and year = 2015
     ) t left join
     orders o
     on o.id = i.id and o.half_month = t.half_month and
        o.month = t.month and o.year = t.year
group by i.id, t.half_month, t.month, t.year;
```

Note: you might have other sources for the `id` and date parts.  This pulls them from `orders`.

Answer (score 0):

IF you know the entire dataset has an occurance of each half_month, month, year combination you could use the listing of those 3 things as the left side of a left join.  That would look like this:

```
Select t1.half_month, t1.month, t1.year, t2.ID, t2.nbr_ord from
(Select half_month, month, year)t1
Left Join
    (SELECT id, half_month, month, year, SUM(nbr_ord)nbr_ord
    FROM Orders
        WHERE month = 7
        AND year = 2015
    GROUP BY id, half_month, year, month)t2
on  t1.half_month = t2.half_month
and t1.month = t2.month
and t1.year = t2.year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.id, m.half_month, m.year, t.nbr_order
FROM (
    SELECT Id, sum(nbr_order) AS nbr_order
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY id
    ) t
INNER JOIN Orders m
    ON t.Id = m.id
WHERE m.month = 7
    AND m.year = 2015;
```